# Display DIV inline which contain P block

Tags: html, css

I would like `div.div-block` and `p.div-p` to remain their default `display:block`, however, `div-inline` to be `display:inline`.  The desired result is three horizontal `div's` each with several vertically stacked `p's` blocks.

I've tried `div.div-block div {display:inline;}`, but `div.div-inline` are still vertically positioned.  When I add `div.div-block div p {display:inline;}`, the `div's` are horizontal, but so are the `p's`.

```
<div class="div-block">
    <div class="div-inline">
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-inline">
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-inline">
        <p class="p-block">Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6fAx/)? Or like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6fAx/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy.  Yes.  Having a hard time telling the difference between `display:block` and `display:inline-block`

Comment: Take a look at [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530751(v=vs.85).aspx). You will be able to tell the different in no time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `display: inline-block` with a set width.  The width is important because when your content grows past "bla bla bla" you will run into wrapping issues.  Also, `vertical-align: top` is needed to position text at the top.

```
.div-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top; }
```

Also, if you care about IE7 compatibility, you need some IE7 hacks.  I commonly use the following for IE7 compatibility:

```
.div-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;  // IE7
    *zoom: 1;          // IE7
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top; }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z73LS/)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is probably `inline-block`. If you make your `.div-inline` class have `div.div-inline {display:inline-block;}`, they will position next to each other. Of course wrapping still works, so if the div would fall off the page, it still wraps the whole block.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is float left to the inline div you are talking about.

```
.div-inline{
    float : left;
    width:33%;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

You have to take care of clearfix for continuous flow of next content on new block. You also need to set width depending upon number of columns you want. 
Working fiddle here with clear fix and width.

http://jsfiddle.net/kXpX2/3/

Comment: Make sure you clear your floats if you need to keep displaying content below as usual http://jsfiddle.net/kXpX2/1/

Comment: This runs into issues when the `p` content grows.  See http://jsfiddle.net/kXpX2/2/